# How to deploy .NET Core application with Angular

Tags: .net-core

How can I deploy a .NET Core app with Angular? I don't want to use Azure.

Comment: Build both of your projects, core and angular. then publish the folder to IIS.

Comment: Will it been seen global and do I need a domain name and how do I connect to db

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The question is rather wide, but ye, there is no requirement for using Azure. (Of course, there are a lot of teams using .net core but running on AWS or GCP)

So first of all, you need to decide the running environment: Linux (NGINX/Apache), or Windows (IIS/Window Service). Then you need to config the app to point to correct folder.

Then you have the option to build and publish the code (either automatic by git or manual)

Also refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: The link you shared is redirecting me to azure ,could you elaborate more or may I have your contact please ?

Comment: I am planing on using digital ocean with LAMP server on it but don't know how to go about it

Comment: @Jokoyoski The link is not exclusively for Azure, it's rather general environment config. So is LAMP, you probably look for the Linux category